# extjs form submit inside of a for loop to upload multiple files

Tags: javascript, extjs

```
        var form =this.up('form').getForm();

        Ext.getCmp('loadingImage').show();

        var gifNameViewString = getFileNameOnly(Ext.getCmp("fileUpload").getValue());

        var gifNameView = gifNameViewString.split(", ");

        for(var i=0; i<gifNameView.length; i++)
        {

            var filename = 'upload/'+gifNameView[i];

            if(form.isValid())
            {  
                form.submit({url: './fileuploading.php,                          
                    success: function(p,o)
                    { 
                        alert("success");


                    },
                    failure: function(fp,o)
                    { 
                        alert("fail");
                    }
                    });
            }

         }
```

by clicking the browse button from file field I have selected the list of files to upload and the last file only gets uploaded.

the form contains Ext.form.field.File to upload.

Comment: You are not waiting for the first file upload to complete before your code starts the next upload using the same field. You have to remove the for loop and may only call the second form submit from the callback function of the first submit.

Comment: thank for your reply, the first file always goto failure function the last file  only going to success function.

Comment: Check this component for doing multiupload instead of using loops. [MultiuploadComponent](http://ext4all.com/post/extjs-4-multiple-file-upload.html). Hope it helps!